# How do I display the attachment's file size of a node?

Tags: 7, nodes, files

Is there any way in Drupal 7 to display the attachment's file size of a node through the manage file / display of the file field, or is this programmatically achieved?

Comment: Are you using the media module with file entity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this hardcoded with the `$node` object by doing so (preferably in theme_preprocess_node in `template.php`) :

If you field `field_my_field` as a single value :

```
$file = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_my_file');
if ($file) {
    $file_size = $file[0]['filesize'];
    $file_size_formated = format_size($file_size);
}
```

If you field `field_my_field` as a multiple value :

```
$files = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_my_file');
if ($files) {
    $files_size_formated = array();
    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
        $file_size = $file['filesize'];
        $files_size_formated[] = format_size($file_size);
    }
}
```

In template.php you should have something like this :

```
// This function allow one preprocess_node function per content type
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = &$vars['node'];
  // Preprocess function for each node type
  $function = __FUNCTION__ . '_' . $node->type;
  if (function_exists($function)) {
    $function($vars);
  }
}

function mytheme_preprocess_node_my_content_type(&$vars) {
  $node = &$vars['node'];
  $file = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_my_file');
  if ($file) {
      $file_size = $file[0]['filesize'];
      $vars['file_size_formated'] = format_size($file_size);
  }
}
```

Then in you `node--my-content-type.tpl.php` you can print your var `$file_size_formated` where you want like this for example :

```
<div class="file-size"><?php print $file_size_formated; ?></div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so in the template.php I should have: 
`function cs_emcdda_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $file = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_pub_file');
    if ($file) {
        $file_size = $file[0]['filesize'];
        $file_size_formated = format_size($file_size);
    }
}

and in my custom node template

            <div class="attachments">
                <?php print render($content['field_attachment']); ?>
</div>`

Comment: You need to get $node, for that add `$node = &$vars['node']` at the beginning of your function. Also add a condition on `$node->type == 'your_content_type'`

Comment: Ok, its working great, thank you so much fo your help @pbonnefoi, the website does not allow me vote in your answer, as soon as its possible, you have my vote :)

Comment: I think you can mark the answer as the right answer for now (it will give you some reputation I think ;-))

Answer (score 1):

You can also modify the theme function [theme_file_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.module/function/theme_file_link/7) in your `template.php` to add the file size to link with something like this:

```
function YOURTHEME_file_link($variables) {
  // ...

  $file_size = format_size($file->filesize);

  return '<div class="file">' . $icon . ' ' . l($link_text, $url, $options) . '<span class="file-size">' . $file_size . '</span></div>';
}
```

Comment: This is better and clearer than the accepted answer.