# How do I display the file size of attachments on a node templates?

Tags: theming, 8, nodes, entities, files

Is there any way to display the file size of attachments on a node through the node template programmatically?

I read [How do I display the attachment's file size of a node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121640/how-to-display-the-file-size-of-attachments-on-a-node-in-drupal-7) but it seems that the answer for that questions is only valid for Drupal 7, and those approaches aren't valid for Drupal 8 node templates.